# calculating sum of floor function regardless of greatest common divisor

Tags: number-theory, summation, gcd-and-lcm, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I hope something good happens to you.

we denote that $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is floor function and $(a, b):=d$ is greatest common divisor between $a$, $b$.

we know that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{b-1} {\left\lfloor \frac{ai}{b}\right\rfloor}=\frac{(a-1)(b-1)}{2}+\frac{d-1}{2}$$

where positive integer $a$, $b$. But it depends on $d$.

Here is my question.

Is there any theorem calculating $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{b-1} {\left\lfloor \frac{ai}{b}\right\rfloor}$ regardless of $d$?

Comment: I'd like to calculate $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{b-1} {\left\lfloor \frac{ai}{b}\right\rfloor}$. But I don't want to use the $d$.

Comment: But $d$ can be evaluated fast and only once... maybe you can find another algorithm, but probably slower.

Comment: Suppose there is such a formula. Let $N$ be the result. Then $d = 2N - ab - a - b$. I.e., such a formula would also give us an easy formula for the gcd of two numbers. No such formula for the gcd is known (and I'm pretty sure that such a formula with a fixed number of operations can be proven not to exist). Thus all you can hope for is an algorithm, and as N74 has said, it is highly unlikely to be any easier than finding the gcd.

Comment: I understand. So, can I know the research on the algorithms related to the formula that I want?